# Relation between LiquiBase, Maven and Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, build-automation, liquibase

I am new to schema migration, so I am kind of lost:

LiquiBase: Schema Migration, Maven: Build Automation, Jenkins: Continious Integration. I am using bitBucket for source control.

I can run LiquiBase through command line, Maven or Jenkins.

1. Does Jenkins have its own build automation or I have to use the Maven plugin for builds? If it has its own build automation then I can just connect Jenkins and LiquiBase and not worry about Maven.

If Jenkins doesn't have a build automation
2. Can I use the LiquiBase Maven plugin in the pom.xml to connect LiquiBase and Maven. Then connect it to Jenkins by using the Jenkins Maven plugin or any other way?

Comment: this would be a beautiful sample question here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/85819/devops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are all completely separate tools, which you seem to understand at least some.

Maven - a tool that does a lot and provides plugins to do even more. Probably tries to do too much. The main things it does are around compiling and packaging Java code. It also can run unit tests, generate documentation, and generate a project website. When plugins are added it can do things like static code analysis, database schema migration, alternative packaging (i.e. to build Eclipse plugins, features, or products, or Android programs, or...)

Jenkins - a tool for Continuous Integration - which in its most basic form includes waiting for things to change in a source code control tool, running a build tool (which might also include tests), and archiving built artifacts to a known location.

Liquibase - a tool for keeping database schema changes in sync with the accompanying code that uses the database.

You asked "Does Jenkins have its own build automation or I have to use the Maven plugin for builds?"

Jenkins doesn't "natively" know how to build anything. It can use Maven, it could use Ant, it could use make, it could use shell scripts, it could use your own home-brewed abomination of batch files and perl. It does have some built-in understanding of Maven projects since it comes from the Java community and is itself built with Maven. You didn't mention what language/platform you are using, so it isn't clear whether choosing Maven as your build tool is appropriate. If you are using Java or another JVM-targeted language, then Maven might be appropriate.

So, if you are using Java to build a web-based application that uses a database and you want to practice continuous integration to make sure that your application is always passing its automated tests and always has deployable artifacts, then these three tools would be good to use together.

Getting down to the final bits - there are many different ways to use Liquibase. It has different commands that do different things, and you can run those commands in different ways. One way is to use Maven to run the commands.

**I would suggest that if you are new to all this it would probably be best to start by using Liquibase from the command line rather than trying to use the Liquibase Maven plugin. Once you get an understanding for how it works, determine if using Maven decreases any 'pain' you are experiencing using the command line.**

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins can integrate with maven or any other build automation tool - you just need to install the plugin and choose which version you want to use and it will be downloaded when you run your job with maven the first time. This would be great because you will have maven for all your projects.

But, if you just have this project with maven and don't have access to install plugins in jenkins you can use [maven-wrapper](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper) which is available since maven 3.3.x and run with java 7. You can use liquibase goals with maven-wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Hello sir if you want to run liquibase via maven just you must add the plugin on poom and the locations which contains xml migrations  and parameters database 
so you have two ways. 
Working with maven and add plugin you can watch this video it will explains you how to integrate liquibase via maven:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyWIqN_QjVE&t=19s
Second ways: you will install plugin liquibase on jenkins  this video will explains you how to do it :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAfLsS0BTTQ&t=25s
I hope that will be helpfull for you.